# IsMouseOver when mouse captured

Tags: wpf

I've got an IsMouseOver trigger on my element. I've also got a drag action happening, whereby another element captures the mouse, and thus the IsMouseOver trigger never happens, yet I explicitly want it to happen on certain elements when I drag over it (mouse captured and all). Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question?

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked years ago, but just in case someone lands here from a search engine (just like me), here is how I solved the problem for myself. Instead of using `IsMouseOver` property, use hit-testing in your code to determine if mouse is inside your control:

```
bool IsMouseOverEx = false;

VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, d =>
{
  if (d == this) 
  {
    IsMouseOverEx = true;
    return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
  } 
  else 
   return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
}, 
ht => HitTestResultBehavior.Stop, 
new PointHitTestParameters(Mouse.GetPosition(this)));

if (IsMouseOverEx) 
{
  //Do whatever you need in case of MouseOver
}
```

N.B. If you haven't read the question, note that this method is a workaround for situations where the mouse is "captured" and therefore `IsMouseOver` property is not working correctly. In normal situations, you should always use `IsMouseOver`.

Comment: This is great, but note that you can use a simpler overload to get the same result:

`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, Mouse.GetPosition(this));`

Answer (score 0):

When the user is dragging something, the mouse is "captured" during that moment, and mouse-events don't get sent to the controls that the mouse passes over. Only the control that actually "captured the mouse", receives mouse events. Thus, you need to handle those events there. This should be easy.
If you have any problem feel free to email me with some sample-code and I'll check it for you. Best of wishes.